# Why does it consume so much memory when I multiply two CSR matrices using scipy?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix

I use a [Scipy CSR representation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.csr_matrix) of a 800,000x350,000 Matrix, let's say its `M`. I want to calculate the dot product `M * M[0:x].T`. Now depending on the value of `x` the memory consumption grows. `x=1` is not noticeable but if `x=2000` the multiplication process takes around 8 gigabyte of RAM.

I wonder what happens when i calculate this product and why it takes so much memory in comparison to storing the sparse Matrix (around 30Mb). Is the matrix expanded for the multiplication?

Comment: Csr uses its own compiled multiplication.  See the sourse code on github for for a reference paper.

Comment: Does this happend when using linalg module ?

Comment: I don't think this is an issue, but just to make sure, test `M*N` where `N` is shaped like `M[0:x].T` but independent (a copy or freshly made).

Comment: Is the 30Mb number the size of `M` or `M * M[0:x].T`? If it's the size of `M`, how big is `M * M[0:x].T`?

Comment: @user2357112 see my posted answer. The 30Mb number was related to M as csr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By investigating the results and memory consumption over time and after each operation I found out that the reason is the result of the sparse matrix multiplication. Indeed there are many zero-values in `M`. But the result of `M*M.T` is a matrix containing only 50% zeros. Thus the result consumes a lot memory.

**Example**: Let's assume each row vector of `M` has a none-zero field at the same index but other than that is *sparse*. Then the result of `M*M.T` would not be *sparse* at all (no zero-values).

Nonetheless, thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

The compile core of `csr` matrix multiplication is found at

https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/0cff7a5fe6226668729fc2551105692ce114c2b3/scipy/sparse/sparsetools/csr.h

starting around line 500, the `csr_matmat...` function.  It includes a reference to a math paper that it is based on.

The Python code called with `A*B` is `__mul__`.  Look at the version for your `csr` matrix to make sure that it is calling `self._mul_sparse_matrix`, which you will see ends up calling `self.format + '_matmat_pass1'` (and `pass2`).

Assuming it isn't resorting to the dense versions, you'll have to study the underlying algorithm to understand whether this memory use is realistic or not.